# Gremlin/TinkerPop - propertyMap() has values but Vertex.properties() is empty

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

When I do `g.V().propertyMap()`, I'm able to get properties stored on vertices. However, when I actually iterate `g.V()` and try to get the properties myself, there don't appear to be any.

Here is a code example:

```
    System.out.println("propertymap: " + g.V().propertyMap());
    g.V().propertyMap().forEachRemaining(e -> System.out.println(e.toString()));
    Iterator<Vertex> vi = g.V();
    while (vi.hasNext()) {
        Vertex vertex = vi.next();
        System.out.println("keys for " + vertex.label() + ": "
                + vertex.keys()
                + " properties.hasNext: "
                + vertex.properties().hasNext());
    }
```

And the corresponding output:

```
propertymap: [GraphStep(vertex,[]), PropertyMapStep(property)]
{Name=[vp[Name->Justin]]}
{Name=[vp[Name->Bob]]}
keys for Person: [] properties.hasNext: false
keys for Person: [] properties.hasNext: false
```

As you can see, the `forEachRemaining` call is able to correctly output the mapping of a property key to a `VertexProperty` that maps the key to a value.

But, my code to iterate the same set of vertices `g.V()` manually isn't able to find any properties at all.

I think I have some basic misunderstanding here of what's going on (just started learning how to use this), would love to be enlightened about what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer in the docs! https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_properties_of_elements

> For bytecode-based requests, graph elements have reference detachment and thus only return the id and label of the elements. While this approach alleviates a potential performance problem that the script approach exposes, it is still important to follow the practice of being specific about the data that is required by the requesting application as it won’t arrive on the client side without that declaration.

It seems that remote servers return a trimmed-down result that doesn't include any properties that aren't explicitly requested. Kind of surprised that this was so hard to find an answer to given that it feels like it'd be a somewhat common issue (that's nearly impossible to debug) for a beginner like me haha.